# How to create correct callback for cairo_pdf_surface_create_for_stream()?

Tags: c, pdf-generation, cairo

I need to output a PDF to a file descriptor, and I was thinking of using Cairo and `cairo_pdf_surface_create_for_stream()`:

I have a write function, that has this signature:

```
static cairo_status_t cairowrite(void *fp, unsigned char const *data, unsigned int length);
```

It returns `CAIRO_STATUS_SUCCESS`.

Now, how do I hand this function over as callback?

I tried this:

```
cairo_write_func_t (*wfunc)(void *, unsigned char const *, unsigned int);
wfunc = (cairo_write_func_t)&cairowrite;
surface = cairo_pdf_surface_create_for_stream((cairo_write_func_t)wfunc, fp, (double)realwidth, (double)realwidth);
```

But I'm getting compiler warnings: `warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type` Which is on the line where I do `wfunc = &cairowrite;`.

What am I doing wrong?

The callback function gives this gcc error: `cairo_status_t` but has to be of type `cairo_write_func_t`.

With clang I get this error:

```
qrencode.c:250:11: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'cairo_write_func_t (*)(void *, unsigned char const *, unsigned int)' from
      'cairo_write_func_t' (aka 'cairo_status_t (*)(void *, unsigned char const *, unsigned int)')
    wfunc = (cairo_write_func_t)&cairowrite;
          ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved!**

I have the function definition:

```
static cairo_status_t cairowrite(void *fh, unsigned char const *data, unsigned int length);
```

And this is how I pass the callback:

```
surface = cairo_pdf_surface_create_for_stream((cairo_write_func_t)cairowrite, fp, (double)realwidth, (double)realwidth);
```

I don't use the intermediate function pointer anymore. clang and gcc don't give any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to define the function pointer with

```
cairo_status_t (*wfunc)(FILE *, unsigned char *, unsigned int) = &cairowrite;
```

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int funp(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}

int call(int a, int b, int (*ptr)(int, int)) {
  int result = ptr(a, b);
  return result;
}

int main() {
  int (*ptr)(int, int) = &funp;
  int r = call(3, 5, ptr);
  std::cout << "Result " << r << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Result 8
```

Comment: Erm, you'r example simply describes general use of function pointers in C++, that was not my question. I need to know how a function can have two types at the same time. And a libcairo related example would be nice, too.

Comment: Yes, you're right :). I was initially distracted by the `cairo_write_func_t` type and provided the example above, then I realized it is inappropriate. However I thought the "extended" definition of the function pointer would have worked. Sorry it didn't.